# Google Search using Java programmatically

Tags: java, google-search, google-search-appliance

Can I perform a Google search using Java code? For example, if I search for "New York," will it send me the data stating all the information in a **structured** manner, such as JSON or XML data? Could you please share the code and or give me any API which does this?

Comment: You can use the Google API.

Comment: But I couldn't find any suitable API. custom search API is for a particular site. If you have something in mind could you please share?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19168929/is-there-any-way-to-return-google-search-results-to-xml-or-json-without-being-a

Comment: Thanks. I have used https://developers.google.com/knowledge-graph/ for this purpose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A sample code for google knowledge search.

Generate API using https://console.developers.google.com/apis/dashboard > credentials > Create credentials > API key

```
import java.util.List;

import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Async;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.google.api.client.http.GenericUrl;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequestFactory;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpResponse;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport;

@Service
public class GoogleSearchService {


    @Async
    public void searchGoogle(List<String> keywords){
        try {
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            HttpTransport httpTransport = new NetHttpTransport();
            HttpRequestFactory requestFactory = httpTransport.createRequestFactory();
            JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
            GenericUrl url = new GenericUrl("https://kgsearch.googleapis.com/v1/entities:search");
            url.put("query", "Kolkata");
            url.put("limit", "1");
            url.put("indent", "true");
            url.put("key", "xxxxxx");
            HttpRequest request = requestFactory.buildGetRequest(url);
            HttpResponse httpResponse = request.execute();
            String responseString = httpResponse.parseAsString();

            JsonNode node = mapper.readTree(responseString).get("itemListElement").get(0).get("result");
            System.out.println(node.get("name"));
            System.out.println(node.get("@type"));
            System.out.println(node.get("detailedDescription").get("articleBody"));

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Are you using "Custom Search API" for this?? Can you tell me which api are you using? in Custom Search API i need to configure custom search engine via adding domains, which can be a hassel because seach can be performed on any topic. if there is other than custom search api, let me know.

Comment: I have used google client API to establish HTTP connection to the service, run the query and get the response.

Comment: can you elaborate more on this api? i cant find it on google cloud console. is it same as custom search?

Comment: To do Search You have use Google's client API. This code snippet will prepare the Http request and call the Google search service. Use below URL ,knowledge search https://console.developers.google.com/apis/library/kgsearch.googleapis.com?q=google%20search&id=95e19e95-aaf7-4c07-93e7-204b594a5992&project=api-project-337207222569&folder&organizationId